# Swift 4 MapKit check if mark is near to my location

Tags: swift, location, mapkit

I want to check when my position is changing if my location is near the Mark. I have marks with unique position. If i near for example 10m from mark i want to display alert. How i can do that?

[image: a busy cat]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Get visible annotations.
2. Calculate distance between your position and the mark.

e.g.

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    guard let myLocation = locations.first else { return }

    let annotationSet = mapView.annotations(in: mapView.visibleMapRect)
    for annotation in annotationSet {
        guard let annotation = annotation as? MKPointAnnotation else { continue }
        let loc = CLLocation(latitude: annotation.coordinate.latitude,
                             longitude: annotation.coordinate.longitude)
        let distance = myLocation.distance(from: loc)
        if distance < 10.0 { Show Alert }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this delegate from CLLocationManager:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let myLoc:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate
    let distance : CLLocationDistance = mark1.distanceFromLocation(myLoc)

    if distance < 10.0 { //Show Alert }
}
```

Comment: What about calculate two lines above in a for loop?

Comment: Even if you have 900 marks wouldn't you just show one alert? You could just set up an bool or count variable in the for loop, and if count variable is greater than 1 or bool is set to true, show your alert or execute next part of your code.